# Python: See if one set contains another entirely?

Tags: python, set

Is there a fast way to check if one set entirely contains another?

Something like:

```
>>> set([1, 2, 3]).containsAll([2, 1])
True

>>> set([1, 2, 3]).containsAll([3, 5, 9])
False
```

Comment: For "multiset" see [python - How to check if all items in a list are there in another list? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147751/how-to-check-if-all-items-in-a-list-are-there-in-another-list) .

Answer (score 169):

Those are lists, but if you really mean sets you can use the [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=issubset#frozenset.issubset) method.

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3])
>>> t = set([1,2])
>>> t.issubset(s)
True
>>> s.issuperset(t)
True
```

For a list, you will not be able to do better than checking each element.

Comment: I get a strange feeling of dejavu when I see this answer

Comment: you have to be aware of the semantics of `issubset()` is not `contains()`

Answer (score 44):

For completeness: this is equivalent to `issubset` (although arguably a bit less explicit/readable):

```
>>> set([2,1]).issubset(set([1,2,3]))
True
>>> set([2,1]) <= set([1,2,3])
True

>>> set([3,5,9]).issubset(set([1,2,3]))
False
>>> set([3,5,9]) <= set([1,2,3])
False
```

Comment: The problem is is a = set([]) and b = set(['a','b']) then a.issubset(b) is True

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki Why is this a problem?

Comment: @EugeneYarmash it is a subset but it is not an element

Answer (score 9):

You can use either [`set.issubset()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) or [`set.issuperset()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issuperset) (or their operator based counterparts: `<=` and `>=`). Note that the methods will accept **any iterable** as an argument, not just a set:

```
>>> {1, 2}.issubset([1, 2, 3])
True
>>> {1, 2, 3}.issuperset([1, 2])
True
```

However, if you use operators, both arguments must be sets:

```
>>> {1, 2} <= {1, 2, 3}
True
>>> {1, 2, 3} >= {1, 2}
True
```

Answer (score 6):

One option is left untouched -- subtraction:

```
>>> {1, 2} - {1, 2, 3}
set([])
>>> {1, 2, 3} - {1, 2}
set([3])
```

Basically, you check what elements in the first list are not in the second.

I found it very handy since you could show what values are missing:

```
>>> def check_contains(a, b):
...     diff = a - b
...     if not diff:
...         # All elements from a are present in b
...         return True
...     print('Some elements are missing: {}'.format(diff))
...     return False
...
>>> check_contains({1, 2}, {1, 2, 3})
True
>>> check_contains({1, 2, 3}, {1, 2})
Some elements are missing: set([3])
False
```

Answer (score 6):

If you suspect a set to be a subset of another, and intersect those two sets together, the result is equal to itself if it is a subset.

```
a = [2,1,3,3]
b = [5,4,3,2,1]
set(a).intersection(set(b)) == set(a)
>>True
```

Comment: Let `A = set(a)` and `B = set(b)` for sanity. Then this comparison is efficiently reducible to `len(A.intersection(B)) == len(A)`. That is, the sets themselves need *not* be compared element-wise; only the cardinality of these sets need be compared. Even this optimization is probably insufficient to render this approach preferable, however. The dramatically more readable *and* efficient `issubset()` and `<=` approaches are almost certainly what everyone want.

Comment: @CecilCurry True - I used the word 'cardinality' incorrectly as it is a length measurement.  I've updated the wording.
Your optimization is an error based on my error.  Not an optimization.
The literal wording of "intersection()" reads more explicit than the overloaded implications of ">=" and stating that "issubset()" is easier to read is kind of an elimination of the obvious since it is the most popular answer.  Feel free to contribute a creative solution beyond repeating others' answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> set([1,2,3]).issuperset(set([2,1]))
True
>>> set([1,2,3]).issuperset(set([3,5,9]))
False
```

Comment: Consider to format you answer properly and add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Below function return 0 if mainlist doesn't contains sublist fully and 1 if contains fully.

```
def islistsubset(sublist,mainlist):
     for item in sublist:
             if item in mainlist:
                     contains = 1
             else:
                     contains = 0
                     break;
     return contains
```

Comment: This is O(n^2) while using set operations as in some of the existing answers is much faster.  This can also be written simply `any(item in mainlist for item in sublist)`.

Comment: Agree infact I could also write
   def islistsubset(sublist,mainlist):
         contains = 1
         for item in sublist:
                 if item in mainlist:
                         continue
                 else:
                         contains = 0
                         break;
         return contains

So only 2 assignments per call

Comment: @BobinMottiThomas You can just directly return True or False without creating any temporary variable.
    for item in list_a:
        if item not in list_b:
            return False
    return True