# How to check if all of the following items are in a list?

Tags: list, python, inclusion

I found, that there is related question, about how to find if at least one item exists in a list:
[How to check if one of the following items is in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287/python-check-if-one-of-the-following-items-is-in-a-list)

But what is the best and pythonic way to find whether all items exists in a list?

Searching through the docs I found this solution:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> set(['a', 'b']) <= set(l)
True
>>> set(['a', 'x']) <= set(l)
False
```

Other solution would be this:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> all(x in l for x in ['a', 'b'])
True
>>> all(x in l for x in ['a', 'x'])
False
```

But here you must do more typing.

Is there any other solutions?

Comment: What's wrong with `set(smaller) <= set(larger)` ?

Comment: I think your second solutions with 'all' looks just fine and pythonic to me.

Comment: Same question as [Python: See if one set contains another entirely? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765892/python-see-if-one-set-contains-another-entirely) except for the list/set distinction.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Operators like `<=` in Python are generally not overriden to mean something significantly different than "less than or equal to".  It's unusual for the standard library does this--it smells like legacy API to me.

Use the equivalent and more clearly-named method, `set.issubset`.  Note that you don't need to convert the argument to a set; it'll do that for you if needed.

```
set(['a', 'b']).issubset(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: didn't know you could pass the list directly as an argument to issubset ... nice !

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, I'm pretty OK with the idea of `<=` and `issubset` meaning the same thing. Why do you dislike it?

Comment: @Just: Primarily, because it's not obvious what `<=` means for a set without either looking it up in the docs or having a prior knowledge of what it means in set theory, whereas everyone knows what `issubset` means automatically.

Comment: You know the mathematical operator for (non-proper) subset? it basically looks pretty much like a rounded <= ;)

Comment: love this solution. is there a way to get an index location or a list value instead of a bool (True:False)?

Comment: The (non-proper) subset mathematical operator is a (partial) order relation (in a context where it makes sense). 
Thus it makes sense to denote it `<=`

Answer (score 73):

I would probably use [`set`](http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR26/PQR2.6.html#Sets) in the following manner :

```
set(l).issuperset(set(['a','b']))
```

or the other way round :

```
set(['a','b']).issubset(set(l))
```

I find it a bit more readable, but it may be over-kill. Sets are particularly useful to compute union/intersection/differences between collections, but it may not be the best option in this situation ...

Comment: Actually, `MySet.issubset(MyOtherSet)` and `MySet <= MyOtherSet` are the same.

Comment: @wok : oh I didn't know that, but I think the <= syntax is a bit confusing as a similar syntax can be used with lists, but with a very different meaning.

Comment: it's not really that confusing if you recall the inclusion defines a partial order on any set of sets. It's actually slightly confusing that `<=` has the meaning it does for sequences: one might expect it to mean 'is a subsequence` of rather than lexicographical ordering.

Comment: @aaronasterling : mmm, I personnally don't think too much about "partial order" when I type code :-), but I agree on the fact that using `<=` with sequences also feels strange, somehow ...

Comment: Comparison operators only defining a partial order--whether or not you know what it's called :)--are fairly unusual.  I think most people intuitively expect that `!(a <= b)` implies `b <= a`, which a partial order does not--both `set([1]) <= set([2])` and `set([2]) <= set([1])` are false.

Comment: I ran into a little gotcha here I'd like to mention: If you use this method, you *are* converting your lists to sets, which means no duplicates. `set(['a','a']).issubset(['a'])` returns `True`.

Answer (score 25):

I like these two because they seem the most logical, the latter being shorter and probably fastest (shown here using `set` literal syntax which has been  [backported](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes) to Python 2.7):

```
all(x in {'a', 'b', 'c'} for x in ['a', 'b'])
#   or
{'a', 'b'}.issubset({'a', 'b', 'c'})
```

Comment: The "all" solution is the quickest when you measure it with timeit(). This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

What if your lists contain duplicates like this:

```
v1 = ['s', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'p']
v2 = ['s', 's', 'h']
```

Sets do not contain duplicates. So, the following line returns True.

```
set(v2).issubset(v1)
```

To count for duplicates, you can use the code:

```
v1 = sorted(v1)
v2 = sorted(v2)


def is_subseq(v2, v1):
    """Check whether v2 is a subsequence of v1."""
    it = iter(v1)
    return all(c in it for c in v2)
```

So, the following line returns False.

```
is_subseq(v2, v1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not OP's case, but - for anyone who wants to assert intersection in *dicts*  and ended up here due to poor googling (e.g. me) - you need to work with `dict.items`:

```py
>>> a = {'key': 'value'}
>>> b = {'key': 'value', 'extra_key': 'extra_value'}
>>> all(item in a.items() for item in b.items())
True
>>> all(item in b.items() for item in a.items())
False
```

That's because `dict.items` returns tuples of key/value pairs, and much like any object in Python, they're interchangeably comparable

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be:

```py
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
potential_subset1 = ['a', 'b']
potential_subset2 = ['a', 'x']
print(False not in [i in l for i in potential_subset1]) # True
print(False not in [i in l for i in potential_subset2]) # False
```

What makes my solution great is that you can write one-liners by putting the lists inline.

Answer (score 1):

An example of how to do this using a lambda expression would be:

```
issublist = lambda x, y: 0 in [_ in x for _ in y]
```

Comment: Please add comments to explain/elaborate your answer

Comment: Note that using `_` as a variable name is confusing in this case. This is because by convention, `_` is used for a variable whose value you do not use ("throwaway variable"). see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/4948719

Comment: @Nephanth 3 years later... thanks now I know.

Answer (score 0):

### Short syntax

I discovered a very readable syntax while experimenting on the Python interpreter.

```py
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> (6 or 7) in my_list
False
>>> (2 or 6) in my_list
True
>>> (2 and 6) in my_list
False
>>> (2 and 5) in my_list
True
```

### List of items to search for

If you have a long list of objects to search for, held in a `sub_list` variable:

```py
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> sub_list = ['x', 'y']
```

If any (at least one) item is contained in the superset (`or` statement):

```py
>>> next((True for item in sub_list if next((True for x in my_list if x == item), False)), False)
False

>>> sub_list[0] = 3
>>> next((True for item in sub_list if next((True for x in my_list if x == item), False)), False)
True
```

If all items are contained in superset (`and` statement), then `sub_list` is a full subset. Also featuring a bit of [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```py
>>> next((False for item in sub_list if item not in my_list), True)
False

>>> sub_list[1] = 2
>>> next((False for item in sub_list if item not in my_list), True)
True
>>> next((True for item in sub_list if next((True for x in my_list if x == item), False)), False)
True
```

Comment: The top syntax _looks nice,_ but it's misleading. It's actually only using one number in the `in` statement. So `(2 or 6) in my_list` is `True` because `(2 or 6)` is `2`, but `(6 or 2) in my_list` is `False` because `(6 or 2)` is `6`.