# How to check if all elements of a list match a condition?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I have a list that contains many sub-lists of 3 elements each, like:

```
my_list = [["a", "b", 0], ["c", "d", 0], ["e", "f", 0], .....]
```

The last element of each sub-list is a sort of flag, which is initially 0 for each sub-list. As my algorithm progresses, I want to check whether this flag is 0 for at least one element. Currently I use a while loop, like so:

```
def check(list_):
    for item in list_:
        if item[2] == 0:
            return True
    return False
```

The overall algorithm loops as long as that condition is satisfied, and sets some of the flags in each iteration:

```
while check(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        if condition:
            item[2] = 1
        else:
            do_sth()
```

Because it [causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/) to remove elements from the list while iterating over it, I use these flags to keep track of elements that have already been processed.

How can I simplify or speed up the code?

---

<sub>See also [Pythonic way of checking if a condition holds for any element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342601/) for checking the condition for any element. Keep in mind that "any" and "all" checks are related [through De Morgan's law](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168603/), just as "or" and "and" are related.</sub>

<sub>Existing answers here use the built-in function `all` to do the iteration. See [How do Python's any and all functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389490) for an explanation of `all` and its counterpart, `any`.</sub>

<sub>If the condition you want to check is "is found in another container", see [How to check if all of the following items are in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931541/) and its counterpart, [How to check if one of the following items is in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740287). Using `any` and `all` will work, but more efficient solutions are possible.</sub>

Comment: Looks like your data structure is not ideal for your problem. If you explained the context a little more maybe we could suggest something more appropriate.

Comment: Maybe you could replace the items with `None` or `[]` as you iterate over the list instead of removing them. Checking the whole list with 'check()` iterating over all the items before each pass on the inner loop is a very slow approach.

Comment: I edited this question to try to make it easier to read and meet current style guidelines; but now it seems evident that it was originally motivated by an XY problem. It would have been better (and actually addressed the performance concern cited) to filter the list properly, rather than look for "better" ways to handle the flags.

Answer (score 549, accepted):

The best answer here is to use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all), which is the builtin for this situation. We combine this with a [generator expression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) to produce the result you want cleanly and efficiently. For example:

```
>>> items = [[1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
>>> all(flag == 0 for (_, _, flag) in items)
True
>>> items = [[1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 0]]
>>> all(flag == 0 for (_, _, flag) in items)
False
```

Note that `all(flag == 0 for (_, _, flag) in items)` is directly equivalent to `all(item[2] == 0 for item in items)`, it's just a little nicer to read in this case.

And, for the filter example, a list comprehension (of course, you could use a generator expression where appropriate):

```
>>> [x for x in items if x[2] == 0]
[[1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
```

If you want to check at least one element is 0, the better option is to use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) which is more readable:

```
>>> any(flag == 0 for (_, _, flag) in items)
True
```

Comment: My fault on the use of lambda, Python's all does not accept a function as the first argument like Haskell et. al., I changed my answer to a list comprehension as well. :)

Comment: @HampusNilsson A list comprehension is not the same as a generator expression. As `all()` and `any()` short circuit, if, for example, the first value on mine evaluates to `False`, `all()` will fail and not check any more values, returning `False`. Your example will do the same, except it will generate the entire list of comparisons first, meaning a lot of processing for nothing.

Comment: it also works if you do `all([ cond(i) for i in range (n) ])`

Comment: @CharlieParker Making it a list comprehension like that just makes things slower, as discussed in my previous comment. You want to use a generator expression (no square brackets) because that way it can short-circuit.

Comment: @GarethLatty ah, interesting point. Not sure why the optimization works but I didn't realize that `all` worked for lists as inputs which was the use case I cared about (e.g. debugging or lists that already exist). Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: `all` works for any iterable.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to check if any item in the list violates a condition use `all`:

```
if all([x[2] == 0 for x in lista]):
    # Will run if all elements in the list has x[2] = 0 (use not to invert if necessary)
```

To remove all elements not matching, use `filter`

```
# Will remove all elements where x[2] is 0
listb = filter(lambda x: x[2] != 0, listb)
```

Comment: You can remove `[...]` in `all(...)` since it can then create a generator instead of a list, which not only saves you two characters but also saves memory and time. By using generators, only one item will be calculated at a time (former results will be dropped since no longer used) and if any of them turns out `False`, the generator will stop calculating the rest.

Comment: Note for python3; `filter()` returns an iterable, not a list. Thus the line would be `listb = list(filter(lamba x: x[2] != 0, listb))`

Answer (score 8):

You could use itertools's takewhile like this, it will stop once a condition is met that fails your statement. The opposite method would be dropwhile

```
for x in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[2] == 0, list)
    print x
```

Answer (score 1):

this way is a bit more flexible than using `all()`:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 0]]
all_zeros = False if False in [x[2] == 0 for x in my_list] else True
any_zeros = True if True in [x[2] == 0 for x in my_list] else False
```

or more succinctly:

```
all_zeros = not False in [x[2] == 0 for x in my_list]
any_zeros = 0 in [x[2] for x in my_list]
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply say `all_zeros = False in [x[2] == 0 for x in my_list]` or even `0 in [x[2] for x in my_list]` and correspondingly for `any_zeros`? I don't really see any remarkable improvement over `all()`.

Comment: no, your version - `all_zeros = False in [x[2] == 0 for x in my_list]` evaluates to `False`, while mine evaluates to `True`. If you change it to `all_zeros = not (False in [x[2] == 0 for x in my_list])` then it is equivalent to mine. And `0 in [x[2] for x in my_list]` is obviously only going to work for `any_zeros`. But I do like the succinctness of your idea, so I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use `itertools.ifilter`. This checks truthiness  and process
(using `lambda`)

Sample-

```
for x in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x[2] == 0, my_list):
    print x
```