# The best way to check if all elements of a list matches a condition in for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

My question is quite similar to [How to check if all elements of a list matches a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163/how-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-matches-a-condition).
But I couldn't find a right way to do the same thing in a for loop.
For example, using all in python is like:

```
>>> items = [[1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]]
>>> all(item[2] == 0 for item in items)
False
```

But when I want to use the similar method to check all elements in a for loop like this

```
>>> for item in items:
>>>    if item[2] == 0:
>>>        do sth
>>>    elif all(item[1] != 0)
>>>        do sth
```

The "all" expression cannot be used in here. Is there any possible way like "elif all(item[2] == 0)" to be used here. And how to check if all elements in list match a condition in a for loop?

Comment: Why would you want to use a loop, if Python has built-in uses like `all` and `any`?

Comment: Because I have one For loop, and a if condition. I just want to add an else condition to check if all elements match one condition. And I just want to know is there a simple way for using 'all' and 'any' in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an `if` and an `else`, you can still use the `any` method:

```
if any(item[2] == 0 for item in items):
    print('There is an item with item[2] == 0')
else:
    print('There is no item with item[2] == 0')
```

The `any` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10666320/5488275).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
items = [[1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]]

def check_list(items): 
    for item in items:
        if item[2] != 0:
            return False
    return True

print(check_list(items))
```

If you want to make it a bit more generic:

```
def my_all(enumerable, condition):
    for item in enumerable:
        if not condition(item):
            return False
    return True

print(my_all(items, lambda x: x[2]==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
prinBool = True
for item in items:
    if item[2] != 0:
     prinBool = False
     break
print prinBool
```

Comment: This only prints if `False`, not if `True`.

Comment: Edited Answer, It will print both

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop with the `else` clause:

```
for item in items:
    if item[2] != 0:
       print False
       break
else:
    print True
```

The statements after `else` are executed when the items of a sequence are exhausted, i.e. when the loop wasn't terminated by a `break`.

Comment: Thank you, I just want to know is there any way to check all elements at one time in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

With `functools`, it will be easier :

```
from functools import reduce

items = [[1, 2, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0]]
f = lambda y,x : y and x[2] == 0  
reduce(f,items)
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for item in items:
    for x in range (0,3):
        if item[x] == 0:
            print "True"
```