# Linking up statements using the 'and' keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing this following:

```
if ycoords[0] > 0 and ycoords[1] > 0 and ycoords[2] > 0:
    # do stuff
```

Can you shorten this code by doing something like:

```
if (ycoords[0] and ycoords[1] and ycoords[2]) > 0:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163/how-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-matches-a-condition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you could use `all`:

```
if all(x > 0 for x in ycoords):
```

or `ycoords[:3]` if `ycoords` has more than 3 elements.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can however simply use `min` to simplify the test syntactically:

```
if min(ycoords[0],ycoords[1],ycoords[2]) > 0:
    # do stuff
```

and given that `ycoords` exactly has three elements, even shorter:

```
if min(*ycoords) > 0:
    #do stuff
```

you can here, as @Tagc says, omit the asterisk (`*`):

```
if min(ycoords) > 0:
    #do stuff
```

but this will result in some overhead.

Another option is to use an `all`:

```
if all(x > 0 for x in [ycoords[0],ycoords[1],ycoords[2]]):
    # do stuff
```

or again, if `ycoords` contains only these three elements:

```
if all(x > 0 for x in ycoords):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: "even shorter: `if min(*ycoords) > 0`". And *even* shorter: `if min(ycoords) > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Something that is not intuitive is that `and`:

> "neither **and** nor **or** restrict the value and type they return to False and True, but
>   rather return the last evaluated argument"

Just open a python terminal and do:

```
>> 4 and 3
3
```

**Why is this important to take in account?**

You might think that:

```
(ycoords[0] and ycoords[1] and ycoords[2]) > 0
```

is equivalent to:

```
ycoords[0] > 0 and ycoords[1] > 0 and ycoords[2] > 0
```

or that is equivalent to:

```
(bool(ycoords[0]) and bool(ycoords[1]) and bool(ycoords[2])) > 0
```

but it's instead equivalent to:

```
ycoords[2] > 0
```

So, be careful because the interpreter is not doing what you think is doing.