# Selenium Python assert all elements in list have some text

Tags: python, list, selenium, assert

Guys how can i assert that all elements in my list have at least 1 word that i need
for example:

```
mylist = ['Burton  white', 'Burton High', 'Burton Durable']
```

and i want to verify all elements in my list have word `Burton`

Comment: if it has 1 word you want to remove it from the list?

Comment: `all('Burton' in x for x in mylist)`

Comment: it is helped me thank you falsetru)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if all elements of a list matches a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163/how-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-matches-a-condition)