# Deleting rows in a file using Python

Tags: python-2.7, file-handling, delete-row

I have input files "input.dat" contain some values like this :

```
41611   2014    12  18  0   0
41615   2014    12  18  0   0
41625   2014    12  18  0   0
41640   2014    6   14  3   3
42248   2014    12  18  0   0
42323   2014    12  18  0   0
42330   2014    8   13  7   7
42334   2014    12  18  0   0
42335   2014    12  18  0   0
...
```

I have many dataset files but seems so many unwanted data
How to delete many rows for this case 41640 and 42330 and its entire row values at instant. For now I used this script:

```
with open(path+fname,"r") as input:
    with open("00-new.dat","wb") as output: 
        for line in input:
            if line!="41640"+"\n":
                output.write(line)
```

The result: The data 41640 is still exist in output. Any ideas??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting a specific line in a file (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your condition - how it is now it checks if the whole line is equal to `41640`. Each `line` is instead equal to the whole row of data you are reading followed by a `\n`. Fixed version of your program looks like this:

```
with open("00-old.dat","r") as input:
with open("00-new.dat","wb") as output:
    for line in input:
        if "41640" not in line:
            output.write(line)
```

To delete multiple lines you can use `all()` combined with a list comprehension as for instance described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163/how-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-matches-a-condition/10666320),

```
if all(nb not in line for nb in del_list):
    output.write(line)
```

where `del_list` is a list of values you want deleted,

```
del_list = ["41615", "41640", "42334"]
```

Also, due to Python's [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html) your original condition will always evaluate to `True`. That is because even if the `41640!=line` was false, the `\n` is added to it and interpreted (after conversion) as `True`. Basically, the `!=` is evaluated first, instead of the string concatenation followed by a `!=`.

Comment: great..it works..and how about imposing more number to be deleted as well?

Comment: @Azam edited, consider looking at the cited post and another variant of the approach, `any()`. They come in handy.

Comment: thanks again. Managed to get the answers at both suggestion.