# Check whether all elements of a NumPy array match a condition

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements

For a given 2 dimentional arrays such as below, i need to check if all the elements are less than 0.2.

```
a = np.array([[0.26002, 0.13918, 0.6008 ],
              [0.2997 , 0.28646, 0.41384],
              [0.41614, 0.36464, 0.21922]])
```

Here is my code, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163/how-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-matches-a-condition).

```
 res = abs(a<0.2)
 all(i==True for i in res)
```

But the code complains with

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Is that an array or a list?

Comment: it is a 2 dimentional array

Comment: Use `abs(a<0.2).all()`?

Comment: why downvote?
how can i improve my question?

Comment: I did not downvote either the question or the answer here. But it would be great if you could acknowledge my comment above.

Comment: @coldspeed yes, it works well. if you write it as an answer, i will approve it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Btw abs(boolean condition) makes no sense. I suppose you meant abs(array) < 0.2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key is to use [`np.all`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) here:

```
(np.abs(a) < 0.2).all()
# False

(a < 1).all()
# True
```