# how to address all items of a list at once?

Tags: python

so im trying to see if all the ints in a list are odd, or even, or both odd and even. I have a general framework down, but is it possible for me to address all the ints in a list at once, and see if they are odd or even?

Comment: How can something be odd *and* even?

Comment: Define "at once".

Comment: @MattDMo Schrödinger's number.

Comment: @MattDMo xD I think they meant if the entire list is odd or even or has both odd or even in it

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 that makes sense...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163/how-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-matches-a-condition

Comment: Actually OP, do you mean to check if the entirety of the list contains only even integers or only odd integer, or a mix of both? Or are you simply trying to loop through your list, checking if each integer is odd or even?

Comment: @CrazyChucky thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)

```
allEven = all(x % 2 == 0 for x in data)
allOdd = all(x % 2 != 0 for x in data)
```

Similarly, `any()` for contains at least one odd or even

> both odd and even

That's not possible.. ? Unless you mean within any given list, it contains a mix of both, in which case

```
oddAndEven = not (allOdd or allEven)
```

Comment: yeah sorry about the wording, i meant if all the ints are odd, even, or a mix of odds and evens

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
all(i%2==0 for i in your_list)
```

for even. It will return True if all numbers are even. Similarly for odds:

```
all(i%2==1 for i in your_list)
```

Comment: True, i updated it, cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [2, 4, 6]
#li = [1, 3]
#li = [1, 2, 3]

even = all(item % 2 == 0 for item in li)
odd = all(item % 2 == 1 for item in li)
mixed = not even and not odd

print('even', even)
print('odd', odd)
print('mixed', mixed)
```