# logical evaluations of multiple boolean variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, boolean-logic

Assuming have m different boolean variables, c1, c2,..cm. How to evaluate whether all of them are true, or any one of these elements is not true, etc. It can be very efficient to check them one by one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if all elements of a list matches a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163/how-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-matches-a-condition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all):

```
c = [True, False]

print(any(c))
# True

print(all(c))
# False
```