# Split list item and remove split items if both are not contained in another list in Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop, split

I have a list, called `nwk`, with two values in each row. I would like to use `split()` to separate the values of each row, and then compare both of those values to another list of integers, called `vals`. If both of the values in a row in `nwk` are not contained in `vals`, I would like to remove that row from `nwk`. Here is what I have so far:

```
for line in nwk:
    a = [ (int(n) for n in line.split()) ]
    if a[0] not in vals:
        nwk.remove(line)
    else:
        if a[1] not in vals:
            nwk.remove(line)
        else:
            continue
```

However, when I print nwk, the code has merely removed 1/2 of my original lines in nwk, which I know to be incorrect. How may I fix this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: the variable `nwk` is a file or a list?

Comment: could you share a sample from your file?

Comment: I'd say include input and expected output as well

Comment: You need to define your problem a little more precisely. When do you remove a line? When either value in the line is not contained in the integers list, or when neither value is contained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` is your friend:

```
filter(lambda line: any(elem in vals for elem in line.split()), nwk)
```

Nice readings:

- The Python Language Reference » [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)
- The Python Language Reference » [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) / [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)
- The Python Language Reference » [`lambdas`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Test:

```
>>> nwk = ['1 2', '3 4', '5 6', '7 8']
>>> vals = ['1', '2', '5', '6', '8']
>>> list(filter(lambda line: any(elem in vals for elem in line.split()), nwk))
['1 2', '5 6', '7 8']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove the line if both vals in a are in vals then Ou could compare list a to list vals as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931541/python-check-if-all-of-the-following-items-is-in-a-list)
And remove the line if True.

like this:

```
set(['a', 'b']).issubset(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

To use a set makes sense since it removes all double entries in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code:

```
new_list = list()
for line in nwk:
    row_a, row_b = line.split()
    if (row_a not in vals) and (row_b not in vals):
        new_list.append(line)
```

Comment: This was also a very helpful response. I was able to use "in" rather than "not in" and get my desired results. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[row for row in nwk if row[0] in vals and row[1] in vals]
```

This will produce a subset of nwk where each value in columns 1 and 2 are both in val.

```
nwk = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
vals = [1, 2, 5, 6, 8]

>>> [row for row in nwk if row[0] in vals and row[1] in vals]
[[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```