# how to find if a user has a role in a list of given role names in Discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Currently running the below code to find if the author of a message has a role with a given name:

```
    author = await context.guild.fetch_member(context.author_id)
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'premium', context.guild.roles)
    if role not in author.roles:
        some code
```

It works when there is a single role to the role var.

What I want is to see if the message author doesn't have roles that are given in a list. Like the below example - which doesn't work (it doesn't execute the `if` statement even when author has the **"verified"** role):

```
    author = await context.guild.fetch_member(context.author_id)
    role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name in ['premium','verified'], context.guild.roles)
    if role not in author.roles:
        some code
```

**How can I correctly adjust or replace the lambda function to search if any of the given role names are present in author.roles?**

Comment: And what does not work? Where do you have problems?

Answer (score 0):

I prepared code for two scenarios. In the first example, you can use [issubset()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3931655/14048071) which will check if **all roles** from the list are in `author.roles` and second if **any role** is present by using *[any()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any)*.

---

**1. When the user doesn't have all roles from the list:**

```py
author = await context.guild.fetch_member(context.author_id)
role_list = ["premium", "verified"]
roles = [discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=x) for x in role_list] #by looping we can get multiple roles and assign them to list

if not set(roles).issubset(author.roles): #this will execute when user doesn't have all roles from list
    # some code
```

---

**2. When the user doesn't have any role from the list:**

```py
author = await context.guild.fetch_member(context.author_id)
role_list = ["premium", "verified"]
roles = [discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=x) for x in role_list]

if not any(i in author.roles for i in roles): #this will execute only when user doesn't have at least one role from the list
    # some code
```