# check if all element of multiple lists inside a list is identical

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I check if the elements of multiple lists inside a list are identical? The following code is from [Checking if all elements of a List of Lists are in another List of Lists Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597180/checking-if-all-elements-of-a-list-of-lists-are-in-another-list-of-lists-python) but it only counts the number of list in my list, not the elements the lists inside the list. Thanks in advance!

```
x.count(x[0]) == len(x)
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can post your code and an example. It helps in understanding the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You can use this:

```
for i in l:
    if len(set(i)) != 1:
       print('not ok')
       break
else:
    print('ok')
```

2) it is better to use one line statement for this purpose like below:

```
all([len(set(i)) == 1 for i in l])
```

`l` is list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
for prev, next in zip(l[:-1],l[1:]):
    if prev != next:
        return False
return True
```

Comment: I keep rereading the question and I'm no longer sure what it is asking, so I can't tell if my answer is right. Please provide more details, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediate list storing `1` if all elements of a sublist are same. Later, check if lengths of original and intermediate lists are same:

```
lst = [[2,2,2], ['d']]

inter = [1 for x in lst if x[1:] == x[:-1]]
if len(lst) == len(inter):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Or you just need:

```
if all([1 if x[1:] == x[:-1] else 0 for x in lst]):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```