# How to check if the elements within a list of lists have overlapping numerical values

Tags: python, list, range

I am working with a list of lists where some items have overlapping values.

```
list=[[7, 11, 'Feature01'],
      [2, 6, 'Feature02'],
      [31, 59, 'Feature03'],
      [31, 41, 'Feature04'],
      [20, 40, 'Feature05'],
      [25, 30, 'Feature06']
```

For example, in the below items Feature04 lies inside Feature03 coordinates.

```
[31, 59, 'Feature03'], [31, 41, 'Feature04'],
```

Similarly in the below example, Feature06 lies inside Feature05 coordinates.

```
[20, 40, 'Feature05'], [25, 30, 'Feature06']
```

I want to retain only one item in such an overlapping scenario and update the original/master list of lists to save non-overlapping list items.

I found almost similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147751/how-to-check-if-all-items-in-a-list-are-there-in-another-list) but could not get it to work.

Comment: What was the code you couldn't get to work? How do you know it didn't work? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72757439/edit) the question.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the list by the starting point of the interval, tiebreaking based on endpoints of intervals (in descending order). Then, you add an interval if it isn't contained by the most recently added interval to the result:

```py
lst.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
result = [lst[0]]

for entry in lst[1:]:
    current_start, current_end, _ = entry
    last_start, last_end, _ = result[-1]
    if not (last_start <= current_start <= current_end <= last_end):
        result.append(entry)
        
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
[[2, 6, 'Feature02'], [7, 11, 'Feature01'], [20, 40, 'Feature05'], [31, 59, 'Feature03']]
```

Comment: the code is letting pass a list with items as  =[[80, 90, 'Feature01'], [86, 110, 'Feature02']]. I want to filter these cases as well. Could you please advise how to cover this scenario also?

Comment: Which interval do you want to keep / remove in this case?

Comment: I would like to retain item [80, 90, 'Feature01'] from this scenario.

Comment: I think something like `if last_end < current_start:` would work, but you may need to fiddle with the condition a bit.