# How do I check to see if any value in an array is equal to a different value?

Tags: python

I was wondering how I could make and if statement to see if any value in a particular array is equal to another value. Instead of me having to do this

```
if (gray == Span1 and gray == Span2) or (blue == Span1 and blue == Span2) or (gray == Span1 and blue == Span2) or (blue == Span1 and gray == Span2) or (purple == Span1 and purple == Span2) or (purple == Span1 and blue == Span2) or (purple == Span1 and gray == Span2) or (gray == Span1 and purple == Span2) or (blue == Span1 and purple == Span2):
```

I could do something that would allow me to see if a value like Span1 is equal to gray, blue, or purple, in less code. Something like this ->

```
colorArray = ["gray","blue","purple"]
if(Span1 == colorArray) or (Span2 == colorArray) or (Span3 == colorArray):
    doThis()
else:
    doSomethingElse()
```

maybe this will work?

```
 if (Span1 in colorArray) and (Span2 in colorArray) and (Span3 in colorArray):
```

Comment: can you provide sample input and output? A minimal reproducible example is welcome.

Comment: i added what I think you mean

Comment: So you just want to find duplicated elements?

Comment: ... I don't think the example code you provided does what you think it does. Anyway it's either [check if element is in array] or [check if two arrays have some common element]).

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "duplicated elements"... but I want to know how to make an array/list of colors and test if Span1, Span2, and Span3, are equal to any of the colors in that array/list

Comment: what does that do @Epsi95

Comment: can you provide sample Span1, Span2 etc

Comment: Is it [Test if lists share any items in python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170055/test-if-lists-share-any-items-in-python) ? The first snippet of code is quite confusing and I'm not sure what it's supposed to do..

Comment: Or maybe [Python: See if one set contains another entirely? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765892/python-see-if-one-set-contains-another-entirely) .

Comment: what are span1 , span2, span3 ?

Comment: Span1 = findSpan1.get_attribute("class") 
Span2 = findSpan2.get_attribute("class") 
Span3 = findSpan3.get_attribute("class")

Comment: maybe give example, like print(Spain1, Spain2, Spain3 ) ? and then provide there value ?

Comment: Span1 has a possibility of being gray, blue, or purple. same with Span2, and Span3

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code using:

```
(Span1, Span2) in [('blue', 'blue'), ('blue', 'gray')] # etc. full list of possibilities
```

But, as you have symmetrical relationships, you could use sets:

```
{Span1, Span2} in [{'gray', 'gray'}, {'blue', 'blue'}, {'gray', 'blue'}, {'purple', 'purple'}, {'purple', 'blue'}, {'purple', 'gray'}]
```

Even, better, as you have all combinations, just do:

```
{Span1, Span2}.issubset(['blue', 'grey', 'purple'])
```

##### Example

```
Span1 = 'blue'
Span2 = 'grey'
Span3 = 'red'

allowed_colors = ['blue', 'grey', 'purple']

if {Span1, Span2}.issubset(allowed_colors):
    print('1+2 OK')

if {Span1, Span3}.issubset(allowed_colors):
    print('1+3 OK')
```

output:

```
1+2 OK
```

Comment: would this work?

Comment: if ({Span1, Span2, Span3}.issubset(['blue', 'grey', 'purple'])):

Comment: Depends what you need. If you want the three spans to be combinations of those 3 colors with possible duplicates, yes.

Comment: Span1 has a chance of being gray, blue, or purple, and same thing with Span2 and Span3. I'm working on a gambling bot and I have some knowledge of programming with python.

Comment: Then yes, it works

Comment: okay, the curly brackets wouldn't cause an issue?

Comment: What kind of issue? Please try first and let me know if there are specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for-loop:

```py
for a in first_list:
    for b in second_list:
        if a == b:
            #do something
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find if any elements in one list appear in another, then I would use a set like so.

```
def foo(given_list, test_list):
    test_set = set(test_list)
    for element in given_list:
        if element in test_set:
            return True
    return False
A_1 = ['candy', 12, 'thirteen', [], 'blue']
A_2 = ['hand', 15, 'car', 'yellow']
B = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
test_A_1 = foo(A_1, B) # True
test_A_2 = foo(A_2, B) # False
```

This way, test_A_1 will be True and test_A_2 will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mozway for showing me this -

```
if ({Span1, Span2, Span3}.issubset(['pointer gray gray', 'pointer blue blue', 'pointer purple purple'])):
    doSomething()
else:
    pass
```